# What is the best way to externalize URL's?

Tags: java, android, properties, fileinputstream

I have 10 URL's in my application, that are currently hard-coded. I want to externalize this and put it in a file so that my application can read it in.

What is the best way of doing this?

```
private String appURL = "http://..."
private String storeURL = "http://..."
private String someURL = "http://..."
```

Note: I will never be writing out to this file in my app. I want the developer to be able to open up the file, and change the URL if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to externalize strings in an android application is to use string resources. Create file `uris.xml` at `res/values` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="appUrl">http://...</string>
    <string name="storeUrl">http://...</string>
    <!-- etc /-->
</resources>
```

You then can then access the strings by:

```
String appUrl = getString(R.string.appUrl);
String storeUrl = getString(R.string.storeUrl);
//..etc
```

`getString()` is a method of `Context` class. Also keep in mind that you should wait until a `Context` will be initialized before starting access its resources. Hence invoke `getString()` not earlier then at `onCreate()` method of `Activity` or `Application`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the values in a XML "configuration" file, then just read the values from the XML file.

[Example of reading an XML file.](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.xml.parsers/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java.html)

Or just use Android's native res folder XML resources files as pointed out by [Konstantin Burov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156715/what-is-the-best-way-to-externalize-urls/4156846#4156846).

Answer (score 0):

If you want ability to have external flat file to be editable you can simply create a text file on say SD (and have some defaults as static strings or properties). Then your code reads the file (standard Java IO) and pics the changes say in `onCreate` of your Activity

[You can also have such file in /assets folder; see this for example](http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/11/17/using-assets-in-android/)